# Error Message Saying "TweenInfo.new first argument expects a number for time," when using TweenInfo

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a tween, and I am getting an Error Message saying that "TweenInfo.new first argument expects a number a number for time," what is wrong?

```
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new{
    0.75,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    0,
    false,
    0
}
-- later on when I call it
tweenService:Create(v, tweenInfo, Vector3.new(X,Y,Z)) -- v is an Instance of a Part
```

please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into a fun quirk of the lua language. As it turns out, [parentheses are optional in function calls](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.html) when only one argument is supplied.

So what is actually happening in your code is this ...

```
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    { table of arguments }, -- time
    nil, -- easing style
    nil, -- easing direction
    nil, -- repeat count
    nil, -- reverses
    nil -- delay
 )
```

The TweenInfo constructor is expecting a number for the first argument, and instead it's getting a table of values.

So to fix this, just replace the curly brackets with parentheses:

```
local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    0.75,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    0,
    false,
    0
)
```

--Edit : according to the comments, there was also a syntax error in `TweenService:Create()`. I've posted the fix here should others need it as well.

```
tweenService:Create(v, tweenInfo, {
    Position = Vector3.new(X,Y,Z),
})
```

Comment: I tried that, it says that it's unable to set to dictionary.

Comment: Figured out what was wrong, I didn't have the Part info that I wanted to change in a dictionary, and then when I did, didn't have position = Vector3.new, so it was yelling at me for that, thank you for the feedback.