# Roblox Lua giving error "TweenInfo.new first argument expects a number for time" even though I am passing in a number

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am testing an idea to make a script that tweens upon calling a function and passing in items, and I keep getting the error that says "TweenInfo.new first argument excepts a number for time" even though I am passing in a number. Here's my code (also the wait is so it doesn't dissapear before I can see it.:

```
wait(5)
local TweenPartMove = function(Part, Time, EasingStyle, EasingDirection, TimesToRepeat, IfReverse, DelayPerTween, GoalsXCoords, GoalsYCoords, GoalsZCoords)
    local TweeningInfo = TweenInfo.new{
        Time,
        EasingStyle,
        EasingDirection,
        TimesToRepeat,
        IfReverse,
        DelayPerTween
    }
    local TweenGoals = {
        CFrame = Part.CFrame + Vector3.new(GoalsXCoords, GoalsYCoords, GoalsZCoords)
    }
    TweenService:Create(Part, TweeningInfo, TweenGoals):Play()
end
TweenPartMove(script.Parent, 3, Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 0, false, 0, 53, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Use `TweenInfo.new(....)` instead of `TweenInfo.new{....}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Message Saying "TweenInfo.new first argument expects a number for time," when using TweenInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345210/error-message-saying-tweeninfo-new-first-argument-expects-a-number-for-time-w)

Comment: @Kylaaa no, it does not.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, yes that fixed it. Thanks.